# Two elasticsearch queries in one

Tags: elasticsearch

In my index I have a list of movies, with several information (title, year, rating, etc), and a boolean "watched".
When the user clicks a button, I have to display 2 things:

- the list of movies sorted by their date (with pagination)
- the latest "watched" movie

As of now, I have a query with match_all and sorted "desc" for the full list of the movies, and another query with a term filter and a sort desc to get the latest "watched" movie.
Is there a way to combine these two queries in one, so that, for each page of results, I can get the movies sorted by date for said page, as well as the latest watched movie ?

Comment: Please provide your queries. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found the solution after a bit of searching...
I'm using a regular query to get all the movies, and a nested aggregation to get the latest watched movie.
The final query looks like this:

```
GET movies/_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "watched_movies": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "watched": true
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "latest": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1,
            "sort": [{
              "lastWatchAt": {
                "order": "desc"
              }
            }]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }, 
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "boost_mode": "sum",
      "score_mode": "multiply", 
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "gauss": {
            "releasedYear": {
              "offset": "90d", 
              "origin": "now",
              "scale": "365d"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "releasedYear": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```